# chart is not visible in stiwebviewer control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, report, stimulsoft

I have created a report displaying a linear chart. the chart is visible in stimul soft designer preview. but when I load the report in my website using stiwebviewer the chart is not visible.

[image]

Also when I export my loaded report in pdf format I can see the chart again .
what's the problem?

[image]

you can see my report file in [here](https://forum.stimulsoft.com/download/file.php?id=15681).

Comment: what error did you get, open your browser console and look for errors

Comment: there is not any error in browser console

Comment: you get some errors, just you can not find where are... ask them: https://www.stimulsoft.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. 
I was using stimulsoft 2015 dlls . 
When I upgraded my dlls to 2016 the problem solved .